# Looking for lightweight somewhat inexpensive flatmount brake calipers for a road bike shipped from North America

Tags: brakes

Looking for the right brake calipers. I see a lot shipped from China or those that cost $130+ for 2.

I need:
disc brakes
cable pull or cable to hydraulic conversion as I am not switching out my ultegra levers.
Flat mount
Short Pull/road bike
Lightweight @ 140 grams or so each

I see a lot of these at crazy high prices or shipping from China but I need this in about 1 1/2 weeks so I cant wait that long.

Comment: Welcome to the site - this is a Q&A not a forum, and shopping is off-topic because its only of limited local use and goes out of relevance quickly. You can learn more how the site is organised by reading the [tour]

Answer (score 2):

If you can't wait for shipping, then your only option is to go to your local bike shops and see what's in stock now.

Brakes are important - I'd suggest politely not focusing primarily on the price, and instead prioritise compatibility, function, and availibility over appearance/price.

Your other option is to shop on your local auction websites, whether that be ebay or craiglist or gumtree, etc.

And try to have a a backup plan too, in case your primary plan doesn't work.